# Making Twitter Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top scrollable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have Twitter Bootstrap navbar:

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="navbar-inner">
       <div class="container">
```

It's working great but I want to make it scrollable, not stuck at the top.

Changing `navbar-fixed-top` to `navbar-top` solve the scroll issue but makes the contents of the navbar start from the beggining of the screen instead of the grid like it's the case with `navbar-fixed-top`.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `navbar-static-top`.

Actually `navbar-top` doesn't exist so it will make it of the standard look.

Comment: Thank you very much. I searched a lot and couldn't find the answer.

Comment: @Adam: There is alway the "official" [bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) that has every informaton you need.

Answer (score -1):

remove class navbar-fixed-top and add style="margin-top:-40px;" and class="navbar-static-top"

Comment: this way the top navbar just becomes not visible, nothing else